# Update column value divisible by 100

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, pgadmin-4, postgresql-performance

Hello experts I need to update next column value with divisible by 100[image: I need to update value Of B column in C column as shown in figure in postgresql]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Modulo operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-math.html), something along these lines:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET NewBalance = Balance - (Balance % 100);
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you sir I solved my problem with the help of your answer.